# Why is this SVG adopting the height of the parent?

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG that I want to remain at a fixed height/width (560px x 275px) while also being clipped by a polygonal clipping mask.

For some reason, the SVG adapts to be the height of it's parent div, and will not align fully to the left (if you stretch the window of this fiddle, you will see that it starts to wander right.)

How do I:

1. Make sure the SVG keeps the same height
2. Position it to the top-left

http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=onwz4D9y63

```
<div class="quad">
    <svg id="kanye" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 560 375">
        <g>
            <defs>
                <polygon id="SVGID_1_" points="0,0 0,1000 400,1000"/>
            </defs>

            <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
            </clipPath>

            <g id="LwhyVN.tif" style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);">
                    <image style="overflow:visible;" width="560" height="375" xlink:href="http://nymag.com/daily/entertainment/upload/2010/08/what_did_it_cost_to_be_kanye_t/20100803_kanye_560x375.jpg">
                </image>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

.quad {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: green;
        }

#kanye {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the position of `kanye` id to `fixed`. And set the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute of the `svg` element to `none`, in the html.

```
 <svg id="kanye" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
```

Edit:

For it to be aligned to the top-left of the green quad div, just specific `position:fixed` for `kanye` and remove the `top:0` and `left:0` attributes. You'll also need to disable `preserveAspectRatio`

Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/P5ggG/

Comment: sorry for not being clearer, I want it aligned to the top left corner of the green div 'quad

Comment: yes, exactly. So changed .quad to fixed and keep #kanye absolute?

Comment: Key change is to remove the `top:0` and `left:0` from `kanye`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: just kill the `viewbox`

it's always been a nasty attribute and should be avoided when possible